# Integrate Multiple Web application container on a single server

Tags: tomcat, docker, webserver, docker-compose, appserver

I am trying to integrate two web application on a single Server.
I have two applications appA and appB, both are docker containers, Each application have several dependency containers  like Database and other.

I want to integrate both Application like www.MYDOMAIN.com/appA and www.MYDOMAIN.com/appB.

appA uses Apache webserver container which is binded to 80:80 and 443:443
AppB also uses same ports 8085:80 and 1443:443.

But I am unable to access appB  externally like www.MYDOMAIN.com/appB.
but when i tunnel to host, tried localhost:8085 on my browser, i can access appB. AppB is Nginx based Container.

Any suggestions how can we integrate two application(docker based) on apache2.

I want to use http.

Comment: Put another Nginx container in front of these two apps and let it then pass the traffic to apache or nginx based on the url

Comment: Create a network to place them under one same network